# Testing for an active window session

Tags: gnome, kde, screensaver, screen-lock

I'd like to run a cron job to test whether there is an active window session (GNOME or KDE) running on my host. By "active" I mean that in addition to just running, the user is "doing stuff".

In other words, I'd like access to whatever timer a screensaver daemon would use to trigger itself.